# How can I read my djvu books on kobo aura one

Tags: kobo, djvu

It prompts me: no rendering component parsed this document, when I read my djvu books in kobo aura one. Oh, I installed koreader in kobo aura one.I think I should move a file to kobo aura one, but I do not know what this file is and how it works？Could anyone help me?Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you install koreader? Did you follow the installation instructions here: https://github.com/koreader/koreader/wiki/Installation-on-Kobo-devices#newer-model

Comment: I downloaded the file from the web, but not from what you said